# (JS) Using IF/Switch statements to change slider value

Tags: javascript, html

Still getting the hang of Javascript so forgive me if this seems like basic stuff.

I've set up a slider on a web page and the CSS/HTML function perfectly but I'm trying to display a year value to correspond with each value of the slider from 1 to 6.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = 133;

slider.oninput = function() {
  switch (this.value) {
    case 1:
      output.innerHTML = 133;
      break;
    case 2:
      output.innerHTML = 88;
      break;
    case 3:
      output.innerHTML = 60;
      break;
    case 4:
      output.innerHTML = 44;
      break;
    case 5:
      output.innerHTML = 36;
      break;
    case 6:
      output.innerHTML = 26;
      break;

    default:
      output.innerHTML = 133;
  }
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p><span id="demo"></span> BC</p>
</div>
```

Currently it outputs 1 to 6 so it does function and I can set the default value to 133 before input, it just doesn't push out the values I need once the slider is moved.

Is a switch statement the correct tool for this job and, if so, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The reason is `output.innerHTML = this.value;`. That's overriding what you did in the switch.

Comment: If I remove this line, it outputs 133 on every value, even if I remove the starting position value at `output.innerHTML = 133;`.

Comment: ```this.value``` is a string.  Compare with "1", "2", "3"...

Comment: @AndyMcCully That's because it's going to the `default:` case, for the reason explained in the answer. You still have to remove that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.value returns a string. You need to make it return a number in order for your comparison to work. Or compare against strings. Either way, the below example works. Look how I added parseInt(this.value) inside your switch operator.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = 133;

slider.oninput = function() {
  switch (parseInt(this.value)) {
    case 1:
      output.innerHTML = 133;
      break;
    case 2:
      output.innerHTML = 88;
      break;
    case 3:
      output.innerHTML = 60;
      break;
    case 4:
      output.innerHTML = 44;
      break;
    case 5:
      output.innerHTML = 36;
      break;
    case 6:
      output.innerHTML = 26;
      break;

    default:
      output.innerHTML = 133;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p><span id="demo"></span> BC</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Or put a string in the cases: `case '1':`

Comment: That's working perfectly. Thank you! I should have noticed it was a string.